# Converting to Third Normal Form

Tags: database, database-design, third-normal-form

How would you convert this table into Third Normal Form (and what are the resulting tables):

[image]

Comment: How would you convert the table into third normal form?  Show some effort.

Comment: No need to be condescending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the tables:

Film (filmNo, fTitle, dirNo)

Director(dirNo, dirName)

FilmActor(filmNo, actNo, role, timeOnScreen)

Actor(actNo, actName)

Comment: Thanks, just double checking that primary keys are the first attribute of each table. I'm having mental blanks....

Comment: @RThomP Yes, except FilmActor that has a composite key of (filmNo, actNo). Consider that if an actor can play in multiple roles in a single film, then the composite key would be (filmNo, actNo, role)

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks for your help :)