# How many columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I am making a digitize notebook for a company, it has many categories so I am currently making 1 column pr categories and just storing the text at LONGTEXT, but how many columns can I have in a mysql table before it gets too bad?
It has about 70 categories, so I am just wondering if it is smart for me to split them into cat1 and cat2 or just have it in 1 column.

Comment: 1 column with the category identifier and all categories in a separate table

Comment: So It's smarter to have alot of tables instead of many columns?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346125/converting-to-third-normal-form?rq=1

Comment: sure, despite to the number of tables, if you'll need to modify one description field, you'll reach the goal by simple modify it in its dedicated table, instead of modify everywhere it occurs.

Comment: Neither. See normalisation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are designing something wrong. I guess you probably need one category table, and then reference that table from table where you store text.
My wild guess would be 3 tables: user, text, category. User table with some id column, text table has user_id, category_id, text columns, and category has id column.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: Yes, that is excactly what I got. I have 3 tables: users, category and news.
Where in category I have about 70 columns.
I might me formulating myself wrong in the text description?